# Dismissing the keyboard in a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiscrollview, keyboard

Alright, I have a couple of `UITextFields` and `UITextViews` inside a `UIScrollView`, and I'd like to set the keyboard to disappear whenever the `scrollview` is touched or scrolled (except when you touch down inside the text field/view, of course).

My current attempt at doing this is replacing the `UIScrollView` with a subclass, and setting it to call a removeKeyboard function (defined inside the main view controller) inside the *touchesBegan* method. However, this only removes the keyboard for a normal touch, not when the view is simply scrolled. So, what's the best way to remove the keyboard inside a `UIScrollView`?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 145):

Here is the cleanest way to achieve this in iOS 7.0 and above.

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

Or

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
```

In Swift:

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

Or

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
```

Comment: can you give me the swift equivalent code? This dosent seem to work in swift.

Comment: In swift, scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.OnDrag; or scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode.Interactive;

Comment: I tried these two but didnt work. can you pls tell me where should I put these code? either in onTouchesBegan or viewDidLoad? And what is the difference between OnDrag and Interactive? Thanks for the response

Comment: You can set it any time after controls/views are loaded. I'd recommend to put it in viewDidLoad and make sure that the scrollView is connected via IB. Even you can set it in IB. It's named Keyboard attribute under Scroll View section of Attribute inspector.

Comment: OnDrag means to dismiss the keyboard when you started dragging scroll view. Whereas Interactive means whenever you began touches in scroll view.

Comment: interactive means keyboard Disappears when ever we touch a white space?

Comment: It's when you touch inside the scroll view.

Comment: Interactive doesnt trigger in Swift.

Comment: Add added this in IB. (Although does seem to work in Simulator).

Comment: This is working for me however I am getting a warning in console: ```-[UIWindow endDisablingInterfaceAutorotationAnimated:] called on <UITextEffectsWindow: 0x7fde30cb9090; frame = (0 0; 568 320); opaque = NO; autoresize = W+H; layer = <UIWindowLayer: 0x7fde30cb9470>> without matching -beginDisablingInterfaceAutorotation. Ignoring.``` Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: Will it work if there's a `view` inside the `scrollView` and all the `textfields` are inside the `view`?

Comment: Yep, for sure. @iPeter

Comment: which one do you use .onDrag or .interactive?

Comment: Dismiss Interactively.

Comment: Try onDrag then. Some people complained that interactive isn't working well.

Comment: If .interactively is not working - set "Bounce Vertically" to true in IB for the UIScrollView. This is because your content view is not big enough to allow scrolling. You need scrolling in order for it to work

Comment: I found that if the Emoji keyboard is shown and you slide the emojis, this causes the keyboard to hide weirdly - any thoughts on how to fix that?

Answer (score 51):

Bit late but if anyone else is searching an answer to this problem, this is how I have gone about solving it:

1) Create a tap gesture recognizer with a target callback method to dismiss your keyboard using resignFirstResponder on all your fields.

2) Add the tap gesture to the scrollview.

Here's an example:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapGesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyboard)];

// prevents the scroll view from swallowing up the touch event of child buttons
tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;    

[pageScrollView addGestureRecognizer:tapGesture];

[tapGesture release];

...

// method to hide keyboard when user taps on a scrollview
-(void)hideKeyboard
{
    [myTextFieldInScrollView resignFirstResponder];
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me on UIScrollView with UITextFields and UIButtons.

Comment: Can you give me the swift equivalent code for this. Thank you

Comment: See my post below for the Swift version.

Comment: I don't understand why do we need to use TapGesture? There is an option available in storyboard itself. In Keyboard change "Do not dismiss" to "Dismiss on drag".

Answer (score 39):

Although the essence is the same, I prefer less code.

Setting the keyboard to disappear when the scrollView is scrolled in Attributes inspector:

[image: make keyboard disappear when scrollView is scrolled]

Then disappear keyboard when scrollView is tapped:

1. Drag a Tap Gesture Recognizer onto your scrollView
2. [image: Ctrl-Drag]
3. [image: Make an action]
4. Only one line in the action —— `scrollView.endEditing(true)`. If you are using Objective-C, `[self.scrollView endEditing: YES];`

Comment: Action is not required only in Keyboard "Dismiss on drag" is enough.

Answer (score 10):

In **Swift**:

Bit late but if anyone else is searching an answer to this problem, this is how I have gone about solving it:

1) Create a tap gesture recognizer with a target callback method to dismiss your keyboard using resignFirstResponder on all your fields.

2) Add the tap gesture to the scrollview.

Here's an example:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var t1: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var t2: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var t3: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var t4: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var srcScrollView: UIScrollView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        let tapGesture: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "hideKeyboard")

        // prevents the scroll view from swallowing up the touch event of child buttons
        tapGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = false

        srcScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
    }

    func hideKeyboard() {
        t1.resignFirstResponder()
        t2.resignFirstResponder()
        t3.resignFirstResponder()
        t4.resignFirstResponder()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

Look at **keyboardDismissMode** property of UIScrollView.

```
// will hide keyboard when your text field is about to go beyond the keyboard.
vwScrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;

// will hide keyboard instantly once the scroll view started scrolling by user.
vwScrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissOnDrag;

// If you need to hide keyboard on tap of scroll view,consider adding a tap gesture or sub class and override touchesbegan: method.
```

### Swift Version

```
vwScrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
vwScrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
```

Answer (score 4):

Try This

```
[self.selectedViewController.view endEditing:YES];
```

Answer (score 4):

Create a extension class for hiding keyboard when touches scrollview/view anywhere

```
extension UIViewController {
  func hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround() {
    let tap: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(UIViewController.dismissKeyboard))
    tap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    view.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
  }
    
  @objc func dismissKeyboard() {
    view.endEditing(true)
  }
}
```

And call this method in viewDidLoad like

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()
  self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()    
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A bit late but if anyone else is searching an answer to this problem with **Swift 3**:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    view.endEditing(true)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I added the gesture to a subclass of `UIScrollView`, I was having problems with the various gestures in my view tree interfering with each other, such as being able to click on subviews, scroll the view, and have the keyboard dismiss in all cases. I came up with this solution, which can be setup from a superclass of `UIScrollView` or from a `UIViewController`.

The `DismissKeyboardTapGesture` class uses ARC, works with any text fields under the view, and doesn't take over any clicks from subviews like buttons. Also takes advantage of iOS7 scrolling effect to dismiss keyboard.

Setting up from UISScrollView superclass:

```
    _dismissKeyboard = [[DismissKeyboardTapGesture alloc] initWithView:self];
```

or from UIViewController:

```
    _dismissKeyboard = [[DismissKeyboardTapGesture alloc] initWithView:self.view];
```

Here is the class:

```
@interface DismissKeyboardTapGesture : NSObject <UIGestureRecognizerDelegate>

@end

@implementation DismissKeyboardTapGesture

- (id)initWithView:(UIView *)view
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(singleTap:)];
        singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
        singleTap.delegate = self;
        [view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];

        if ([view respondsToSelector:@selector(setKeyboardDismissMode:)]) {
            // Bonus effect to dismiss keyboard by scrolling
            ((UIScrollView *)view).keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
        }
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer
{
    // Don't stop any existing gestures in our view from working
    if (otherGestureRecognizer.view == gestureRecognizer.view) {
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}

- (void)singleTap:(UIGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer
{
    // Close keyboard for any text edit views that are children of the main view
    [gestureRecognizer.view endEditing:YES];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this scroll view delegate method -

link delegate in IB to scroll view and then cop this code (modify as per your need).

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView willDecelerate:(BOOL)decelerate
{         
//sample code    
    [challengeABallotComponent.voterNameTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [challengeABallotComponent.ballotNumberTextField resignFirstResponder];
    [locationInformation.pollingLocation resignFirstResponder];
}
```

This should work. You can try other delegate methods too like

```
   -(void)scrollViewDidScroll: (UIScrollView *)scrollView 
{
//do your stuff
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    extension UIView{
    //Set tag via storyboard 
    func keyboardDissmissInteractiveMode(_ tag:Int){
        if let scrollView = self.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIScrollView{
            scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        }
        if let tableview = self.viewWithTag(tag) as? UITableView{
            tableview.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        }
    }

    func keyboardDissmissOnDragMode(_ tag:Int){
        if let scrollView = self.viewWithTag(tag) as? UIScrollView{
            scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
        }
        if let tableview = self.viewWithTag(tag) as? UITableView{
            tableview.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
        }
    }


    func keyboardDissmissInteractiveMode(_ view:UIView){
        if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView{
            scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        }
        if let tableview = view as? UITableView{
            tableview.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        }
    }

    func keyboardDissmissOnDragMode(_ view:UIView){
        if let scrollView = view as? UIScrollView{
            scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
        }
        if let tableview = view as? UITableView{
            tableview.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
        }
    }
}
```