# Dismiss keyboard with swipe gesture (as in Message app)

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uiresponder

When the keyboard is showing on the iPhone's Messages app, if the user begins a swipe down from the messages tableview and continues into the keyboard area, the keyboard will begin to dismiss. If they move their finger up and down during this process, the keyboard moves with it.

Are Apple doing this with private APIs, or is there a way to control the keyboard like this from (I presume) a gesture recognizer?

Comment: It does not do that on my iPhone. (3GS, iOS 4.3.3)

Comment: Ah, this may hypothetically be in a future OS release then. I would like to discuss how such an effect could be obtained, in principle.

Comment: I believe it is an iOS 5.x feature. Should be out of NDA by now.

Comment: Sadly, this functionality still hasn't appeared in iOS 5.x. Check out my answer for an open source attempt.

Comment: @DanielAmitay I found a [great solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24358901/242933) for iOS 7.1+.

Answer (score 44):

I created a UIView category that provides the desired functionality:

https://github.com/danielamitay/DAKeyboardControl

Edit:
It has indeed been used on the app store.

Comment: simply awesome! (_someone_ needs to accept this as the answer)

Comment: excellent, you should have more than 10 upvotes for that thing!

Comment: aaand it's broken in iOS 8. Guess it's time for everyone to find a new solution!

Comment: There are crashes in this,
swizzled_addSubview.
Dont even know how the crash is occuring

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu Are able to find solution ? I am facing same

Comment: @MikeAlter nope, I've given up on it.

Comment: Ok @CanPoyrazoğlu  if you are still looking for answer  then see mattdipasquale 's Solution it is working ,

Answer (score 34):

The simplest solution is to set the following two properties:

- [`UIViewController : UIResponder` `inputAccessoryView`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23880574/242933)
- [`UITableView : UIScrollView` `keyboardDismissMode`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20039441/242933)

Boom, baby!

Check out [Acani Chats](https://github.com/acani/Chats) [iPhone Client](https://github.com/acani/Chats-iPhone-Client) [`ChatViewController.swift`](https://github.com/acani/Chats-iPhone-Client/blob/master/Chats/ChatViewController.swift) for an example.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Post-iOS 7, all you need is `keyboardDismissMode`.

Comment: I have a UIView which contains the textField. How can i do that?

Comment: @GabyFitcal That's fine. Read all the links above. I updated them.

Comment: tableView.keyboardDismissMode = .OnDrag

Answer (score 30):

Luckily, Apple added the handy property `keyboardDismissMode` on `UIScrollView` to make your life a little easier.

Now your app can behave like Messages.app just by changing a single property on your Storyboard, or alternatively by adding one line of code!

This property uses the new `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode` enum. The possible values of this enum are as follows:

```
UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeNone        // the keyboard is not dismissed    automatically when scrolling
UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag      // dismisses the keyboard when a drag begins
UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive // the keyboard follows the dragging touch off screen, and may be pulled upward again to cancel the dismiss
```

Here’s the Storyboard property to change to dismiss the keyboard on scroll:

[image]

Hope that helps solving your problem

Comment: This is great. Got excited, I have nothing to do but check a box. Then realised my input view attached to the top of my keyboard didn't move with it...doh.

Answer (score 10):

In iOS 7, you can now dismiss the keyboard interactively on a UIScrollView.

[Dismissing the keyboard in a UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143873/dismissing-the-keyboard-in-a-uiscrollview)

Hope that helps someone.

Comment: My answer below contains more details without providing a link that is subject to change in the future

Answer (score 5):

You can use UISwipeGestureRecognizer to do so. I don't know how to implement it using code, but if you are using the new xcode 4.2 beta then heres an easy method:

1. Create an IBAction:

`- (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender;`

1. Go to your view in your xib and set the class for you view to UIControl.
2. Drag and connect the UISwipeGestureRecognizer from the Library to your view.
3. Connect the IBAction (TouchDown) with the UISwipeGestureRecognizer.
4. Write the code to dismiss the keyboard:

   ```
   - (IBAction)dismiss:(id)sender 

   {

     [yourTextField resignFirstResponder];

   }
   ```

Done!

Comment: That would not work. The keyboard would slide down and disappear, but not come back up when the finger moves up again before the gesture is finished.

Comment: Well thats the only method that works to dismiss a keyboard with a swipe gesture that I know. Just wanted to help!

Comment: agree with JonasG.  whereas Apple is probably using a form of UIPanGestureRecognizer under the hood, it requires their own internal knowledge of controlling the frame of the keyboard to get it to slide up and down in the fashion you see in the Messages.app .  the closest thing would be to use a UISwipeGestureRecognizer (or perhaps a UIPanGestureRecognizer, though it would act virtually the same as a swipe in that the down would start the motion and there would be no way to arrest the keyboard from disappearing at that point).

Answer (score 1):

In **swift** you can use below code to get the view container of current keyboard (**if exist**), than you can change is's frame in your code:

```
UIApplication.shared.windows
    .filter{ NSStringFromClass($0.classForCoder) == "UIRemoteKeyboardWindow" }
    .first?.subviews.filter { NSStringFromClass($0.classForCoder) == "UIInputSetContainerView" }
    .first?.subviews.filter { NSStringFromClass($0.classForCoder) == "UIInputSetHostView" }
    .first
```

By the way here are a tool called [Reveal](https://revealapp.com) make you can see the view hierarchical.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to place a hidden button above the text input container. a long strip and when it detects a touchdown and release or cancel then hide the keyboard.

I'm going to try it and i will let you know how i go.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer; They're most likely doing some 'Private API' thing there.

I'm most sure that the keyboard is in an independent view, above your app's window (You do not have access/control to it and it always displays on top, no matter what). The most you can do is have the input view become/resign first responder status, and the keyboard will appear/disappear accordingly: All or nothing.

You may be able to get a handle of the keyboard view and change its frame property (using undocumented properties of documented classes, and undocumented classes), but I'm pretty sure that will get you kicked out of the store.