# ios- listen keyboard notifications of other apps

Tags: ios, iphone, keyboard

Is it possible to get/listen keyboard notifications by other apps in my app.

Obviously when my app is in background.

Comment: If it is possible then you will get all passwords from background :)

Comment: I am talking about only notifications not the data access...system can only generate event...it is possible in android

Comment: You can listen Bluetooth or Sound notification, but I don't know about keyboard notification, When I found. I will forward to you..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9746417/keyboard-willshow-and-willhide-vs-rotation

check the answers of this.. I am not sure but you can get help..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, this would be a huge privacy issue.

All apps on iOS are sandboxed and can't directly interact with other apps or the system.