# Dismiss keyboard with view simultaneously

Tags: ios, ios7, ios8, xcode6

The app I am building has a messaging/chat view controller that has a view with a textView and a button at the base of the view (tab bar is set to hidden). When the view loads, the view with those objects (the textView and the button) in it is at the base of the screen (like how it looks in the iMessage app when you go into a conversation)

Now when the textview is tapped on, obviously the keyboard moves up, and along with that I have managed to get the view to move up and sit right up on top of the keyboard (like when you go to type in a new text message).

Now what I am trying to do is get the view move up and down with the keyboard. As of right now it starts at the bottom. When keyboard goes up, that view is stuck at the bottom for a second or two and then just appears above the keyboard. Same goes for when the keyboard is dismissed.

I wish I could provide pictures but I guess my reputation is not quite cutting it

Is there a way I can match the transitions or animations of the two so they move together as if they are attached?

**The view is initialized**

```
//Create the keyboard UIView
    self.keyboardView =  [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.origin.y + self.view.frame.size.height - (self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar.frame.size.height), self.view.frame.size.width, 50)];
```

**Selector used to move the view**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardFrameDidChange:) name:UIKeyboardDidChangeFrameNotification object:nil];
```

**Selector implemented**

```
- (void)keyboardFrameDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification{
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];

    CGRect kKeyBoardFrame = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] CGRectValue];
        [self.keyboardView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, kKeyBoardFrame.origin.y - self.keyboardView.frame.size.height, 320, self.keyboardView.frame.size.height)];
        self.myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.size.width, self.myTableView.frame.size.height);


}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this here is the keyboard notification

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)

                                             name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification object:nil];

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self

                                         selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)

                                             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
```

**keyboardWasShown**

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification

{
NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
double duration = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
int curve = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"foo" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
CGRect rect=self.viewChatWindow.frame;
rect.size.height=self.viewChatWindow.frame.size.height-kbSize.height;
self.viewChatWindow.frame=rect;

[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(scrollToLast)];
[UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

**keyboardWillBeHidden**

```
- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification

{
double duration = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
int curve = [[[aNotification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] intValue];
[UIView beginAnimations:@"foo" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:duration];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:curve];
CGRect rect=self.viewChatWindow.frame;
rect.size.height=self.view.frame.size.height-rect.origin.y;
self.viewChatWindow.frame=rect;
[UIView setAnimationDelegate:self];
[UIView setAnimationDidStopSelector:@selector(scrollToLast)];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your [keyboardView setFrame:...] in an animation block. You can get the keyboard's animation duration and curve from the notification object:

```
NSTimeInterval duration = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] doubleValue];
UIViewAnimationCurve curve = [notification.userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] integerValue];
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration delay:0 options:curve animations:^{
    self.keyboardView.frame = ...;
} completion:nil];
```

Comment: What if I am using this method to dismiss the keyboard `self.myScrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;`

Comment: Hmm, good question. I'm not very familiar with UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive. Looks like this might be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19118921/moving-a-bar-with-uiscrollviewkeyboarddismissmodeinteractive. Have you tried the solution described there?

Comment: I have tried that and it works perfectly if I am dismissing the keyboard with its natural animation. So thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Using UITextFieldDelegate

This will be your flag that the keyboard is gonna show up

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
//Animate like slide up.
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                         animations:^{
                             //Use offset rather than contentSize
                             scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(x,y);
                         }];
}
```

When your keyboard is dismissed (resignFirstResponder)

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3
                     animations:^{
                         scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0,0);

                     }];
 }
```

Comment: But I am working with a textView...wouldn't this be ideal if I was working with a textfield?

Comment: I think this would just work the same with textview but UITextViewDelegate instead.