# Error when adding input view to textfield iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I'm having an issue when I add a custom input view to my app on iOS 8. This was working perfectly fine on iOS 7 but when switching to iOS 8 everything fails.

This is the stack trace:

```
2014-06-03 21:23:54.237 MyApp[1910:47245] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x1103f9d40>
should have parent view controller:<StopChooser: 0x11083e200> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x110858800>'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042eee35 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000103b919a0 objc_exception_throw + 45
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001042eed6d +[NSException raise:format:] + 205
    3   UIKit                               0x00000001023d94cd -[UIViewController _addChildViewController:performHierarchyCheck:notifyWillMove:] + 184
    4   UIKit                               0x0000000102977a2b -[UIInputWindowController changeToInputViewSet:] + 416
    5   UIKit                               0x0000000102973f56 -[UIInputWindowController moveFromPlacement:toPlacement:starting:completion:] + 185
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010297826a -[UIInputWindowController setInputViewSet:] + 526
    7   UIKit                               0x0000000102973c97 -[UIInputWindowController performOperations:withAnimationStyle:] + 50
    8   UIKit                               0x00000001027559bb -[UIPeripheralHost(UIKitInternal) setInputViews:animationStyle:] + 1054
    9   UIKit                               0x0000000102422afd -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] + 468
    10  UIKit                               0x00000001023235d3 -[UIView(Hierarchy) becomeFirstResponder] + 99
    11  UIKit                               0x00000001029cdbfb -[UITextField becomeFirstResponder] + 51
    12  UIKit                               0x0000000102655d61 -[UITextInteractionAssistant(UITextInteractionAssistant_Internal) setFirstResponderIfNecessary] + 177
lib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
    (lldb)
```

The relevant part being the top few lines. Can someone explain this? All I'm calling is `myTextview.inputView = keyboard`; Keyboard being a UIView created in the storyboard and linked via IBOutlet.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

I encountered this problem before.

**Problem**:

- You have to ensure that the view you will assign to `inputView` or `inputAccessoryView` doesn't belong to any parent view. When you create these views from a xib inside a ViewController, by default they are set as subviews of a superview.

**Solution Tips**:

- Use the method `removeFromSuperview` on the view you will assign to `inputView` or `inputAccessoryView`

Comment: For me, I was both adding them as a subview AND setting them as inputView/inputAccessoryView.  This seemingly worked well in IOS7.  In IOS8, I removed the addSubviews to fix this error.

Comment: @Miro, you don't read the question clear enough. This problem only happens on iOS8. Prior iOS8, everything works well.

Comment: This did not work for me, but my answer below helped me.

Comment: In Swift and in the viewDidLoad method: add self.myToolbar.removeFromSuperview()

Comment: i have a messaging app , i have a inputView ( include textField & Button ) my problem is when i add subview it & press on my cell for show UIMenueController ( on method becomeFirstResponder ) (i get this crash ) why ?

Comment: good to known that having inputAccessoryView with another parent works on 13.4.1, but crashes on 12.4

Answer (score 20):

Just before `becomeFirstResponder` remove the View you use for input from the superview :

```
mTextField.inputView = mInputVeiw;
[mInputVeiw removeFromSuperview];
[mTextField becomeFirstResponder];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

> You have to ensure that the view you will assign to `inputView` or `inputAccessoryView` don't belong to any parent view.

This error is especially annoying as any "input view" created in a storyboard (and thus added to the VC's `view`) cannot be set as the `inputView` or `inputAccessoryView` without causing this crash.

If the input view is not added to the VC's `view`, the input view will not be available for visual editing in the Interface Builder Storyboard. It's only visible in the Storyboard's left pane.

[How to connect Xcode Storyboard's "Simulated Metrics" toolbar to an actual IBOutlet UIToolbar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30494588/how-to-connect-xcode-storyboards-simulated-metrics-toolbar-to-an-actual-ibout)

I'd prefer to make an IB Connection to the `inputAccessoryView` directly in the Storyboard. That causes this crash. A solution I found is to make a secondary IBOutlet connected to the view in the Storyboard, then in `viewDidLoad` remove it from the super view then immediately assign to `inputAccessoryView`. Not sure if I'll end up using this.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    // ...

    [self.keybordView removeFromSuperview];
    self.inputAccessoryView = self.keybordView;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this! "You have to ensure that the view you will assign to inputView or inputAccessoryView don't belong to any parent view." is what finally resolved the issue I was struggling with.

Comment: `inputAccessoryView` is getOnly property.

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. I'm not sure what the issue was before but instead of linking a `UIView` in interface builder, I instead created a `UIView` programmatically and it worked fine.

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? There's a `UITextField` with an `inputView` set as a `UIPickerView`. Where does the `UIView` come into play?

Comment: @CliftonLabrum there is no UIPickerView

Comment: @CliftonLabrum Do this programmatically:
1. create a picker
2. create an empty `UITextField`
3. set the `UITextField.inputView = picker`
4. add `[self.viewcontroller addSubview: myUITextField]`

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I have named a view having a textField 'inputAccessoryView'...

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet CustomView *inputAccessoryView;
```

Error:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception
'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view
controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x7fed7063a1a0> should
have parent view controller:<MyViewController: 0x7fed70606f00> but
requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x7fed710cde00>'
```

Solution:

> Check the naming; do not override if not needed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution creating the UIView programmatically (Like suggested by Milo), but it crashes when its used like a @property. In my case, I needed to create the UIPickerView instance in viewDidLoad and assing to UITextView inputView. When I need to acess the pickerView I get it like this

```
UIPickerView *picker = (UIPickerView *)self.myTextField.inputView;
```

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, the Tuyen Nguyen solution did not work for me.
What worked for me in iOS 8 / Xcode 6 for setting an inputAccessoryView was not to `removeFromSuperview` but instead:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:**MyViewToBeTheUIAccessoryView**];
```

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when I tried to setup my UIDatePicker in my UITextField

```
- (void)setupViews {
    ...
    dobField.inputView = aDatePicker; // Here was the problem
    ...
}
```

My solution, I just "alloc" and "init" my datePicker in ViewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    ...
    aDatePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init]; // My solution
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling `removeFromSuperView` in `viewDidLoad` doesn't seem to work properly in modals. I ended up setting the view hidden, and then removing it from superView in `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

Most answers I was were related to code changes. I found out that deleting an outlet to the UIView inside the main view fixed it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/40037236/464313

Answer (score 0):

My solution for this problem was to add view to inputView, but not to add view controller to parent.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when I return any view from storyboard as `inputAccessoryView`. I fixed it with childViewController. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44219487/1836420).