# Why doesn't input toolbar show when jsqmessages placed in container viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I'm following the SwiftExample from JSQMessagesViewController but attempting to place the ChatViewController into a container view controller.  It works as expected except that the text input toolbar does not show at the bottom.

I have experimented with sizing and looking at the hierarchy debug view to see if the input toolbar may be hidden offscreen, but it does not appear to exist. The toolbar is part of the JSQMessagesViewController xib file.  Why would it not show?

UPDATE:
I see that jsq_configureMessagesViewController explicitly removes the inputToolbar from the view. If I comment out that line as an experiment I get the toolbar to appear, however it then fails with an error regarding having the wrong parent in the view hierarchy.

So obviously there are things I do not yet understand about input views and the view hierarchy.  This thread seems related:

[Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency',](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25761953/terminating-app-due-to-uncaught-exception-uiviewcontrollerhierarchyinconsistenc)

and for what it's worth here is my storyboard showing the container:

[Storyboard diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OOPV.png)

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be unique to the current development branch.  Reverting to an earlier release seems to work.