# becomeFirstResponder cause crash UICompatibilityInputViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, becomefirstresponder

I have a messaging app.
 I have a `UITabeView` in ViewController. I implement my longPressGesture event on my Custom `UITableViewCell` like this to show `UIMenuController` on it ( copy - forward and ... ) :

**AudioMsgCell**

```
-(void)handleLongPress:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gesture
        [self becomeFirstResponder]; // i crash on this Line
        UIMenuController *menu = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        UIMenuItem *delete = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete" action:@selector(Delete:)];
        CGRect targetRect = [self convertRect:[self.bubbleImageView frame]
                                     fromView:self];
        [menu setMenuItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:delete,nil]];
        [menu setTargetRect:targetRect inView:self];
        [menu setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];}
```

i have a `XIB file` include `UITextField` & some `UIButton` and in myviewController i `addSubView` to View.

**TextingViewController**

```
 [self.view addSubview:self.inputView];
```

when I do long press gesture on  cell I get crash on the method

**AudioMsgCell**

```
 [self becomeFirstResponder]
```

I had this problem in past, when I implemented extrakeyboard in iOS 8 but now  when   do gesture on my Cell app crash with this error :

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x14459d620> should have parent view controller:<BLTextingViewController: 0x146801000> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x144a05a00>'
```

please look at this link :
[Error when adding input view to textfield iOS 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029113/error-when-adding-input-view-to-textfield-ios-8/25882277#25882277)

if i remove  addSubView in  ViewController everything is ok But i cant't see  View  ( include TextField  & ... )

**UPDATE:**

if the textField is first responder (this crash not happning).
bug I want to touch my cell when keyboard is resign.

Comment: I'm guessing self.view is a UITableViewCell? So what is self.inputView? Maybe your inputView has a superview set from the XIB you are talking about that is should not have? Have you tried `[self.inputView removeFromSuperView]` before calling `[self.view addSubview:self.inputView]`.

Comment: no  dear peter  [self.view addSubview:self.inputView]; in my viewController that i need add my inputView.  --- > my input view is a View in XIB file & add it on my ViewController by addSubView

Comment: @PeterSegerblom please check again , i update  my question

Comment: What do you want to become first responder?

Comment: @PeterSegerblom i want to show UIMenuControler on my CustomCell