# UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency Exception when displaying UIAlertController

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

When I try to display a `UIAlertController` from my app, the app terminates with an exception `UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency`.

The View Controller is created with a storyboard

[image: From Storyboard editor]

I create and (try to) display the Alert like this:

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *yesButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
...    
}];
[alert addAction:yesButton];

[self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, during execution I get this in the output:

> 2016-08-25 09:46:07.536 TrackYou[10554:3165715] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:`<`UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x13f5afd80> should have parent view controller:`<`ViewController: 0x13f549360> but requested parent is:`<`UIInputWindowController: 0x140043c00>'

From the same `ViewController` I use the `presentViewController` to present a custom ViewController, which works fine.

```
SettingsViewController *controller = [SettingsViewController new];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Any ideas what's causing the problem?

Comment: possibly dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24029113/error-when-adding-input-view-to-textfield-ios-8 ..

Answer (score 1):

I also got this exception and my app crashed. In my case I used UIAlertController and customised the UI,so that UIAlertController will have a label and textfield side by side.

For custom UI of UIAlertController I used following code.

```
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "your title",
                                  message: "your msg",
                                  preferredStyle: .alert)


    let inputFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 90, width: 300, height: 60)
    let inputView: UIView = UIView(frame: inputFrame);

    let prefixFrame = CGRect(x: 10, y: 5, width: 60, height: 30)
    let prefixLabel: UILabel = UILabel(frame: prefixFrame);
    prefixLabel.text = "your label text";

    let codeFrame = CGRect(x: 80, y: 5, width: 235, height: 30)
    let countryCodeTextField: UITextField = UITextField(frame: codeFrame);
    countryCodeTextField.placeholder = "placeholder text";
    countryCodeTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.decimalPad;

    let submitAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Submit", style: .default, handler: { (action) -> Void in

        // your code after clicking submit
    })

    let cancel = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: { (action) -> Void in })


    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.inputView = countryCodeTextField
    }


    inputView.addSubview(prefixLabel);
    inputView.addSubview(countryCodeTextField);


    alert.view.addSubview(inputView);

    alert.addAction(submitAction)
    alert.addAction(cancel)


    present(alert, animated: false, completion: nil)
```

When I run this code,I got the exception

```
  *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x13f5afd80> should have parent view controller:<ViewController: 0x13f549360> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x140043c00>'
```

Then I have removed the below code

```
  alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.inputView = countryCodeTextField
    }
```

My exception gone and no more crash in my app.

Hope this is helpful for somebody. Sorry if it is not understandable,my English is not so good.

Answer (score 0):

I also stuck this problem and find the solution is that you should find the top view controller and present the alert on the top view controller.

**Find the top view controller:**

```
-(UIViewController *)getTopViewController{
            UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

        while (topController.presentedViewController) {
            topController = topController.presentedViewController;
        }
        if (![topController isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            return topController;
    }
```

**and present the alert on top view controller:**

```
UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"Title" message:@"Message" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
UIAlertAction *yesButton = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction *action){
...    
}];
[alert addAction:yesButton];

[[self getTopViewController] presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Unfortunately it didn't solve it for me. Same error :(