# InputView not working in TextFields inside UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c

Inside each of `CollectionViewCells` i have added `UITextField`, that need to take input from picker View.

So I'm assigning inputView as pickerView inside my `CellForRowAtIndexPath`.
When i run the code the input view part is empty. Not having any pickerviews.

> I realize the datasource methods are not getting invoked.

`percentagePicker` is created outlet on my ViewController

This is my cellForRowAtIndexPath method

```
    cell.cropPercent.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cropPercentagesList[indexPath.row];

    UIPickerView *pikerView = _percentagePicker;

    [_percentagePicker removeFromSuperview];

    pikerView.delegate =self;
    pikerView.dataSource = self;

    cell.cropPercent.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    cell.cropPercent.inputView = pikerView;
```

Comment: Why are you removing percentagePicker from superView?

Comment: As suggested in post https://stackoverflow.com/a/25882277/5215474

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of creating an outlet of UIPickerView and assigning it to the pickerView to show as inputView just try the code below.

```
    UIPickerView *pikerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]init];

    pikerView.delegate =self;
    pikerView.dataSource = self;

    cell.cropPercent.textColor = [UIColor redColor];

    cell.cropPercent.inputView = pikerView;
```

Comment: How can i get the values in pickerviews if all are diffrent

Comment: You can specify tag to these pickerViews
pickerView.tag = indexPath.row

Comment: 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderArray initWithObjects:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[2]' This error is coming when i change item in picker before didselect delegate gets invoked

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't get you. Could you please explain the scenario which is causing this error ?

Comment: when i change selection in my pickerView

Comment: Could you please post the code inside the didselect delegate ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149551/discussion-between-saranjith-and-aravind-a-r).

Answer (score 0):

You should move your pickerView code to `viewDidLoad` since it's in your `viewController`. Don't create an instance of new `UIPickerView`;

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
 {
     [super viewDidLoad];

    _percentagePicker.delegate =self;
    _percentagePicker.dataSource = self;
 }
```

In your `cellForRow` just do this and remove other `UIPickerView` code:

```
cell.cropPercent.inputView = pikerView;
yourPickerDataSourceArray = yourSource[indexPath.row];
[percentagePicker reloadAllComponents];
```