# InputAccessoryView docked at bottom

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitoolbar, uikeyboard, uiresponder

I'm trying to achieve similar positioning behavior as the bottom text input bar in Apple's Messages app.

I have tried many approaches, searched high and low and there are many similar questions but none have been satisfactory.

To specify:

1. There is a `UIToolbar` at the bottom of the view
2. The toolbar is to follow the keyboard as the keyboard appears and disappears
3. The toolbar should stay on top of the keyboard when the keyboard is visible
4. When the keyboard is hidden, the toolbar stays ("docked") at the bottom of the view

**The proposed solutions:**

### Manually animate the toolbar in response to keyboard appearance notifications

This solution does not meet a special case of the second requirement (*the toolbar is to follow the keyboard as the keyboard appears and disappears*):

- In iOS 7, `UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissMode` was introduced. It enables an interactive gesture for dismissing the keyboard. As the the user pans past the top edge of the keyboard, the keyboard frame gradually follows. This solution does nothing to accomodate this behavior and just leaves the toolbar stranded at it's animated position.

In addition, this solution also fails to fulfil a special case of the third requirement (*the toolbar should stay on top of the keyboard when the keyboard is visible*):

- Rotation. This solution calls for additional, annoyingly extraneous code (as we will see in the next proposed solution) to rotate the toolbar in response to device rotation.

Another issue with this solution:

- Keyboard height. With this solution, the toolbar it is not assumed to be part of the height of the keyboard, so additional code must be written to support proper insetting of content.

**Next proposed solution:**

### Use `UIResponder`'s `inputAccessoryView`

This solution seems to be the way Apple intended to support this kind of behavior, as it solves all the shortcomings of manually animating the toolbar. But this solution completely misses the fourth requirement (*when the keyboard is hidden, the toolbar stays ("docked") at the bottom of the view*).

---

It seems the solution is to use `UIResponder`'s `inputAccessoryView`, but somehow making the `inputAccessoryView` not move below the view. I'm looking for clean code to accomplish this. There are elaborate, almost noble, attempts elsewhere, but as mentioned, they do not meet the requirements.

In my particular case, I am looking to use `UINavigationController`'s toolbar which entails additional issues as this is not intended behavior for `UINavigationController`. No matter, I'm willing to introduce some hacky fixes to accomplish that.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I was just shown "the" solution by Jason Foreman (@threeve). On your view controller (yes, view controller) add `inputAccessoryView:` and return the view you want to dock at the bottom and move with the keyboard. It just works. The view doesn't actually need to be in your view hierarchy it will be inserted by the view controller automatically.

edit: also implement canBecomeFirstResponder and return YES (as noted by Max Seelemann). reloadInputViews can be handy too.

Comment: You should add that the view controller *also* needs to return `YES` from `-canBecomeFirstResponder` and need to make itself the first responder. But after that -- just magic. +100 ;)

Comment: Sounds interesting, but I don't quite understand. Care to elaborate?

Comment: Wait... I think I understand (I'll test in code): The UIViewController should return a inputAccessoryView, instead of, for example, the UITextView or UITextField.

Comment: Yep, fantastic, this works. It also makes sense semantically. D'oh! Thanks for sharing!

Comment: This also works for the UIToolbar managed by UINavigationController.

Comment: Why are features like this so poorly documented ? Is there a repository or something where undocumented finds like this are collected ? (UINavigationBars can also be popped sideways by calling 'setHidden' in the right places in viewWillAppear, etc.) <- stuff like that ! )

Comment: Would be good to see a complete code example for this "magic" solution.

Comment: The proposed solution generate a retain cycle between the UIViewController and inputView. Maybe it's a bug from iOS SDK, but it causes the UIViewController to never get released, and generating leaks.

Comment: Sadly I can't get this technique working in conjunction with a UITabBar. The inputAccessoryView is just drawn over the tabs.

Comment: I must be missing something. Neither `inputAccessoryView` nor `canBecomeFirstResponder` are being called on my view controller when it is first shown. Am I supposed to add the input view to the view manually as well as returning it from `inputAccessoryView`?

Comment: I got it working by calling `[self becomeFirstResponder]` in `viewDidLoad` of all things.

Comment: I am getting `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistency', reason: 'child view controller:<UICompatibilityInputViewController: 0x159ec54b0> should have parent view controller:<ULPostViewController: 0x157dec330> but requested parent is:<UIInputWindowController: 0x1580f0800>'` error with this method. (iOS 8.3)

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu I think this might occur if you've attempted to add the "accessory" view to the main view controller we're working in. You don't need to manually add it when using as an `inputAccessoryView`.

Comment: I can't believe this works. This is amazing! Great find!

Answer (score 32):

Jonathan Badeen's aforementioned [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23880574/1855040) worked for me. Here's code from [Arik](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24855095/1855040) showing how to implement it (this should go in your appropriate view controller):

```
    - (BOOL)canBecomeFirstResponder{

        return YES;

    }

    - (UIView *)inputAccessoryView{

        return self.inputAccessoryToolbar;  
     // where inputAccessoryToolbar is your keyboard accessory view

    }
```

Comment: problem there when trying to go to a diferent controller, by push or present, the inputAccessoryView still shows

Answer (score 14):

For those looking for Swift version:

Connect your toolbar (in my case '`myToolBar`') on to your view controller. Then override `canBecomeFirstResponder` method and override the getter `inputAccessoryView` variable. Also don't forget to add the `self.myToolBar.removeFromSuperview()` or else xcode will complain.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var myToolBar: UIToolbar!

    override func canBecomeFirstResponder() -> Bool {
        return true
    }


    override var inputAccessoryView:UIView{
        get{
            return self.myToolBar
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.myToolBar.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG, you simplified into absolute minimal!

Comment: In the end i didn't use this code i went with https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController much easier no hassle lol

Comment: I tested with the STVC, but I dislike to add so much bloat of codes just for a basic TextView, and the STVC is not fully adapt to storyboard, need to use XIB. I most disappointed it is not an actual accessories bar view, it doesn't adapt to interactive dismiss as in Whatsapp / iMessage. I still yet to find the better solution. But worth checking out https://github.com/muukii/NextGrowingTextView if all u need is 100% storyboard compatible for simple input TextView. But still, this one not adapt to accessoriesbar view either..

Comment: @DazChong Thanks for sharing

Comment: This solution works well but you don't need to call removeFromSuperview. You can setup a special view in the storyboard without it being added to the view hierarchy, and then hook up its outlet. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37896351/3344977

Answer (score 6):

There's an excellent, easy-to-implement, open-source solution to this from the good folks at Slack: **[SlackTextViewController](https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController)**.

Here's how to implement a view with a docked toolbar in four steps:

1. Install the pod into your project. (http://cocoapods.org/?q=SlackTextViewController)
2. If you're writing an app in Swift, create a header to bridge between your Swift code and their Obj-C classes. [Here's a nice quick walkthrough on that](https://medium.com/@stigi/swift-cocoapods-da09d8ba6dd2). (The bridging header won't be necessary once the classes are translated into Swift, anyone want to collaborate on that?)
3. Create a `MessageViewController` that inherits from `SLKTextViewController`, no need to write any more code than this:

   ```
   import Foundation
   import UIKit

   class MessageViewController: SLKTextViewController {

       required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder!) {
           super.init(coder: aDecoder)
       }
   }
   ```
4. In Storyboard, create a View Controller that inherits from MessageViewController.
5. Test the app on a device or emulator, you'll see a beautiful docked textbar that also (as a bonus) expands as the user writes additional lines of text.

Props to the team at Slack for extracting such a useful pod.

Answer (score 2):

So I know this is an old post and I am not sure if you resolved this or not, but I found a way to get this working. I believe there is a bug in the inputAccessoryView, but I created a hacky solution to behave the way the messages app does. I think I provided all the necessary code to implement the work around. I am going to try and get a more appropriate blog post created sometime in the near future, with a more in depth description with my findings. Any questions, let me know.

```
@property(nonatomic,assign)BOOL isFirstKeyboard; //workaround for keyboard bug

@property(nonatomic,assign)BOOL isViewAppear;

@property(nonatomic,strong)ChatBarView *chatView; //custom chat bar view

@property(nonatomic,strong)UIView *footerPadView; //just to add some nice padding
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//in the view did load
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //more app specific code...
    self.tableView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeInteractive;
    self.chatView.textView.inputAccessoryView = self.chatView;
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
-(void)done
{
    self.isFirstKeyboard = YES;
    [self.chatView.textView becomeFirstResponder];
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void) moveTextViewForKeyboard:(NSNotification*)aNotification up:(BOOL)up
{
    if(!self.isViewAppear)
        return;
    //NSLog(@"keyboard is: %@", up ? @"UP" : @"Down");
    if(!up && !self.isFirstKeyboard)
        [self performSelector:@selector(done) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.01];
    else if(!up & self.isFirstKeyboard)
    {
        self.isFirstKeyboard = NO;
        [self.view addSubview:self.chatView];
        CGRect frame = self.chatView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height - self.chatView.frame.size.height;
        self.chatView.frame = frame;
    }
    else
    {
        NSDictionary* userInfo = [aNotification userInfo];
        NSTimeInterval animationDuration;
        UIViewAnimationCurve animationCurve;
        CGRect keyboardEndFrame;

        [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationCurve];
        [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] getValue:&animationDuration];
        [[userInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] getValue:&keyboardEndFrame];

        // Animate up or down
        [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        if(up)
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.2];
        else
            [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:animationCurve];

        CGRect frame = self.footerPadView.frame;
        CGRect keyboardFrame = [self.view convertRect:keyboardEndFrame toView:nil];
        if (up)
            frame.size.height = keyboardFrame.size.height - self.chatView.frame.size.height;
        else
            frame.size.height = 0;
        self.footerPadView.frame = frame;
        self.tableView.tableFooterView = self.footerPadView;
        [UIView commitAnimations];
    }
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    [self moveTextViewForKeyboard:aNotification up:YES];
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    [self moveTextViewForKeyboard:aNotification up:NO];
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```