# Is there a way to default to the number pad when using the NamePhonePad Swift keyboard type?

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, uitextfield

Right now when using `textField.keyboardType = .namePhonePad`, it will automatically start out showing the alpha keyboard, and you then have to press the number toggle to see the number pad. Is there any way to reverse that and have the number pad show first as the default and then be able to manually toggle to the alpha keyboard?

I know it's possible to create a custom button to be able to toggle the keyboard type, as well as changing the keyboard type based on what they type into the text field, but I just want a way to change its default first keyboard.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set number side as default (while keyboard is open) of name phone pad keyboard type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36543544/how-to-set-number-side-as-default-while-keyboard-is-open-of-name-phone-pad-key)