# How to dismiss telephone number TextView in swift

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, storyboard, swift5.6

[image]

How can I dismiss the keyboard after typing the number? I am new to the UI field. I dismissed the normal keyboard after pressing the return button. But how can I do the same in the telephone number keyboard(on the attached picture's keyboard)

Comment: this is what you are looking for : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28338981/how-to-add-done-button-to-numpad-in-ios-using-swift

Comment: For SwiftUI, you can just simply implement that using `@FocusState`and `ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .keyboard)`. [check this out](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/hiding-the-keyboard)