# Not able to use cocoa pod in swift project

Tags: swift, cocoapods, podspec

I am trying to use SlackTextViewController (https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController) in my app which is written in Swift.

(I am following this -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/26467524/2852500)

After pod install, everything works fine, but when I try to subclass from one of their objective-C classes, build fails with errors like -

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
"_OBJC_CLASS_$_SLKTextViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_CLASS_$__TtC8Appname15Class2 in Class2.o
"_OBJC_METACLASS_$_SLKTextViewController", referenced from:
  _OBJC_METACLASS_$__TtC8Appname15Class2 in Class2.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I followed [Undefined symbols for architecture arm64](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19213782/undefined-symbols-for-architecture-arm64) but then I got the same error for armv7.

My bridging header is as follows:

```
#ifndef Appname_Bridging_Header_h
#define Appname_Bridging_Header_h
#import <GooglePlus/GooglePlus.h>
#import <GoogleOpenSource/GoogleOpenSource.h> 
#import <SLKTextViewController.h>
#import <SLKInputAccessoryView.h>
#import <SLKTextInputbar.h>
#import <SLKTextView.h>
#import <SLKTypingIndicatorView.h>

#endif
```