# Enable both UIScrollView subviews tap and scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, tableview

I've strange problem with customized `UIScrollView` inside a `UITableView` cell. I've a scroll view showed picture below. One scroll view and there are five `UImageView` each of these have an `UITapGestureRecognizer` event. I don't want to disable `UIScrollview`'s `userInteraction` value (specially scrolling) I just want to enable touch event its subviews.

For clear explanation user could use tap (scrollview subviews) and scroll future(scrollView).

This code solve only tap problem when I tap view inside scrollview.

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
```

I've read these posts but still does not solve my problem.

[ScrollView gesture recognizer eating all touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882737/scrollview-gesture-recognizer-eating-all-touch-events?lq=1)

[UITapGestureRecognizer on UIScrollView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27715448/uitapgesturerecognizer-on-uiscrollview?lq=1)

[Detect touch event on UIScrollView AND on UIView's components [which is placed inside UIScrollView]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12243963/detect-touch-event-on-uiscrollview-and-on-uiviews-components-which-is-placed-i?rq=1)

Here is picture scrollview and there are three subview in it.
[image]

Comment: Sorry its not clear. What is happening now and what would you like to happen?

Comment: @jakedunc Sorry for this. It's really hard to explain clearly. I just want to add tap recognizer on view inside scrollview. Also scroll scrollview.