# Xamarin IOS UILabel Tap Gesture inside UIScrollView not working

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, xamarin.ios

I have an UIScrollView and inside this I have an UILabel. I need to detect tap gesture events for the UILabel. At the moment, it' not working. I am new in xamarin IOS, please help. Thanks in advance.

**Here is my Code**

```
UILabel lViewallLabel = new UILabel(new CGRect((View.Bounds.Width / 2) - 20, 270, View.Bounds.Width / 2, 16));
lViewallLabel.Text = "VIEW ALL >>";
lViewallLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Right;
lViewallLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
lViewallLabel.Font = UIFont.SystemFontOfSize(12f);
lViewallLabel.AdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true;
lViewallLabel.UserInteractionEnabled = true;
UITapGestureRecognizer tgrLabel2 = new UITapGestureRecognizer(() =>
       {
             UIAlertView myAlert = new UIAlertView();
             myAlert.AddButton("OK");
             myAlert.Message = "Label was tapped.";
             myAlert.Title = "It worked!";
             myAlert.Show();
        });
lViewallLabel.AddGestureRecognizer(tgrLabel2);
innerView.AddSubview(lViewallLabel);

scrollView.AddSubview(innerView);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have solve the problem using the below code. Small change in code, I have added the UILabel directly to the UIScrollView instead of innerview.

```
UITapGestureRecognizer singleTap = new UITapGestureRecognizer();
singleTap.CancelsTouchesInView = false;
scrollView.AddGestureRecognizer(singleTap);

scrollView.AddSubview(lViewallLabel);
```

This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882737/scrollview-gesture-recognizer-eating-all-touch-events) helped me lot to solve the issue.