# How to receive touch events from a CollectionView embedded inside a UiView embedded inside a UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uicollectionview, touch-event

I have a very long form and created a containerView (UIView) that contains a custom Calendar and several textFields. The UIView is embedded inside a scrollView so that I can scroll the long form.

```
ScrollView
   -ContainerView // UIView
       -CustomCalendar // contains a UICollectionView
       -TextField
       -TextField
        //etc etc..
```

Apple says:

> You should not embed UIWebView or UITableView objects in UIScrollView
>   objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result because touch
>   events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly handled.

To get around that I tried to disable scrolling on the CalendarView but it didn't make any difference:

```
// this is inside the CalenderView file
myCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
```

I got the calendar from [here](https://github.com/Akhilendra/calenderAppiOS) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=srJj8U5d5ok&t=1s) and it uses a collectionView to show the dates and when a date is chosen didSelectItem is triggered.

The problem is since the custom calendar contains a collectionView and it's inside the scrollView when I touch a date didSelecetItem won't run.

**How can I get the calendar's collectionView to receive touch events?**

The calendar works fine when it's not inside the scrollView

```
let scrollView: UIScrollView = {
    let sv = UIScrollView()
    sv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    sv.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
    return sv
}()

let containerView: UIView = {
    let view = UIView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.backgroundColor = .white
    return view
}()

let calendarView: CalendarView = {
    let view = CalendarView() // contains a collectionView
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    return view
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createAnchors()
}

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: scrollView.contentSize.width, height: 1000)
}

func createAnchors() {

    view.addSubview(scrollView)
    scrollView.addSubview(containerView)

    scrollView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    scrollView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

    containerView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.topAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: scrollView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true

    calendarView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.topAnchor, constant: verticalPadding).isActive = true
    calendarView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.leftAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
    calendarView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.rightAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    calendarView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 290).isActive = true

    // textFields are added...
}
```

Here is the file for the CalenderView. There are 2 more files that I didn't include because those are only views that create the weeks and months.

```
class CalendarView: UIView, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout, MonthViewDelegate {


let myCollectionView: UICollectionView = {
    let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
    layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)

    let myCollectionView=UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
    myCollectionView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
    myCollectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    myCollectionView.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    myCollectionView.allowsMultipleSelection=false
    myCollectionView.isScrollEnabled = false
    return myCollectionView
}()

var numOfDaysInMonth = [31,28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
var currentMonthIndex: Int = 0
var currentYear: Int = 0
var presentMonthIndex = 0
var presentYear = 0
var todaysDate = 0
var firstWeekDayOfMonth = 0   //(Sunday-Saturday 1-7)

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)

    initializeView()
}

func initializeView() {
    currentMonthIndex = Calendar.current.component(.month, from: Date())
    currentYear = Calendar.current.component(.year, from: Date())
    todaysDate = Calendar.current.component(.day, from: Date())
    firstWeekDayOfMonth=getFirstWeekDay()

    //for leap years, make february month of 29 days
    if currentMonthIndex == 2 && currentYear % 4 == 0 {
        numOfDaysInMonth[currentMonthIndex-1] = 29
    }
    //end

    presentMonthIndex=currentMonthIndex
    presentYear=currentYear

    setupViews()

    myCollectionView.delegate=self
    myCollectionView.dataSource=self
    myCollectionView.register(dateCVCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numOfDaysInMonth[currentMonthIndex-1] + firstWeekDayOfMonth - 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell=collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! dateCVCell
    cell.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    if indexPath.item <= firstWeekDayOfMonth - 2 {
        cell.isHidden=true
    } else {
        let calcDate = indexPath.row-firstWeekDayOfMonth+2
        cell.isHidden=false
        cell.lbl.text="\(calcDate)"
        if calcDate < todaysDate && currentYear == presentYear && currentMonthIndex == presentMonthIndex {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled=false
            cell.lbl.textColor = UIColor.lightGray
        } else {
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled=true
            cell.lbl.textColor = Style.activeCellLblColor
        }
    }
    return cell
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell=collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor=Colors.darkRed
    let lbl = cell?.subviews[1] as! UILabel
    lbl.textColor=UIColor.white
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell=collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath)
    cell?.backgroundColor=UIColor.clear
    let lbl = cell?.subviews[1] as! UILabel
    lbl.textColor = Style.activeCellLblColor
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = collectionView.frame.width/7 - 8
    let height: CGFloat = 30
    return CGSize(width: width, height: height)
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 8.0
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 8.0
}

func getFirstWeekDay() -> Int {
    let day = ("\(currentYear)-\(currentMonthIndex)-01".date?.firstDayOfTheMonth.weekday)!
    //return day == 7 ? 1 : day
    return day
}

func didChangeMonth(monthIndex: Int, year: Int) {
    currentMonthIndex=monthIndex+1
    currentYear = year

    //for leap year, make february month of 29 days
    if monthIndex == 1 {
        if currentYear % 4 == 0 {
            numOfDaysInMonth[monthIndex] = 29
        } else {
            numOfDaysInMonth[monthIndex] = 28
        }
    }
    //end

    firstWeekDayOfMonth=getFirstWeekDay()

    myCollectionView.reloadData()

    monthView.btnLeft.isEnabled = !(currentMonthIndex == presentMonthIndex && currentYear == presentYear)
}

func setupViews() {
    addSubview(monthView)
    monthView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor).isActive=true
    monthView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive=true
    monthView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive=true
    monthView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 35).isActive=true
    monthView.delegate=self

    addSubview(weekdaysView)
    weekdaysView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: monthView.bottomAnchor).isActive=true
    weekdaysView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor).isActive=true
    weekdaysView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor).isActive=true
    weekdaysView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive=true

    addSubview(myCollectionView)
    myCollectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: weekdaysView.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive=true
    myCollectionView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leftAnchor, constant: 0).isActive=true
    myCollectionView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: rightAnchor, constant: 0).isActive=true
    myCollectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor).isActive=true
}

let monthView: MonthView = {
    let v=MonthView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return v
}()

let weekdaysView: WeekdaysView = {
    let v=WeekdaysView()
    v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=false
    return v
}()

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
}

//get first day of the month
extension Date {
var weekday: Int {
    return Calendar.current.component(.weekday, from: self)
}
var firstDayOfTheMonth: Date {
    return Calendar.current.date(from: Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year,.month], from: self))!
}
}

//get date from string
extension String {
static var dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    return formatter
}()

var date: Date? {
    return String.dateFormatter.date(from: self)
}
}
```

Just for a visual of the CalendarView. The dates (1-30) are a collectionView.

[image]

Comment: I doubt anyone can answer your question since you don't show a single line of code involving `UICollectionView` and `UICollectionViewCell`.  And why would anyone need to know how you make contraints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43248537/4833705) by @Jaydeep and got the [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16885076/4833705) from @zambrey.

*The idea is to tell the gesture recognizer to not swallow up the touch events. To do this you need to set singleTap's cancelsTouchesInView property to NO, which is YES by default.*

You want to tell the scrollView not to eat all the touch events and you do that by adding a single tap gesture recognizer to it and setting the tap’s

```
singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
```

I added the tapGesture in the file that embeds the CalenderView inside the UIView inside the ScrollView and not the file that has the collectionView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    createAnchors()

    // add these 4 lines
    let singleTap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap(_:)))
    singleTap.cancelsTouchesInView = false
    singleTap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(singleTap)
}

// add this target method. I didn't add any code whatsoever inside of it 
func handleTap(_ recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
  // I literally left this blank
}
```