# Allow taps to pass through UITapGestureRecognizer and reach table view below

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitapgesturerecognizer, didselectrowatindexpath

I'm implementing a search controller with a search bar on top and a tableview below which displays the results of the search. I added the following code so that when a user taps on the screen, the keyboard will be dismissed.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard (_:)))
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

@objc func dismissKeyboard (_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let view = self.view {
        view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

However, now when I try to implement the `didSelectRowAt` method of the table view, it doesn't work as the `UITapGestureRecognizer` defined in the code above captures the touch event. Ideally, I'd like the tableview touches to take precedence over the code above, so that when a user touches the tableView, `didSelectRowAt` is called, but when he touches anywhere else on screen, `dismissKeyboard` is called instead.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ScrollView gesture recognizer eating all touch events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16882737/scrollview-gesture-recognizer-eating-all-touch-events)

Comment: yes it does - thank you

Answer (score 2):

Implement **UIGestureRecognizerDelegate** and use return false if the touch is on your tableView.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.dismissKeyboard (_:)))

    tabGesture.delegate = self

    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)
}

func gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceiveTouch touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
    if touch.view?.isDescendantOfView(self.tableView) == true {
        return false
    }
    return true
}
```

That should solve your problem

Comment: You could also `touch.view?.isDescendantOfView(self.tableView) ? true : false`.