# How to hide keyboard on touch the scroll view Background?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6

I went through all the solutions but none are working. I am developing an app for iOS 6, ipad. I want the keyboard to go away when user touches outside (on scrollview)...

Comment: Are you looking for : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143873/dismissing-the-keyboard-in-a-uiscrollview ?

Comment: `[yourtxtFld resignFirstResponder];`

Comment: @sivakumar see my answer that will be solve your problem

Answer (score 6):

Give the following code in viewDidLoad

```
-(void) ViewDidLoad
{
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapScroll = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(tapped)];
tapScroll.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[scrollview addGestureRecognizer:tapScroll];
}
```

And define the function as follows

```
- (void) tapped
{
[self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this one. And i hope it will be helpful.

```
  - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];

        UITapGestureRecognizer *gestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideKeyBoard:)];
        gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
        [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
    }

    -(void) hideKeyBoard:(UIGestureRecognizer *) sender
    {
        [self.view endEditing:YES];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

set the scrollview Delegate to self

```
self.scrollView.delegate=self;
```

then

```
-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{


if (sTitle.isFirstResponder) {
    [sTitle resignFirstResponder];
}
}
```

Comment: Or better to use:
`-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code to hide the keyboard:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(hideTheKeyBoard:)];
    gestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
    [scrollView addGestureRecognizer:gestureRecognizer];
}

-(void) hideTheKeyBoard:(UIGestureRecognizer *)sender
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  UITapGestureRecognizer *tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapped:)];
   [tapRecognizer setNumberOfTapsRequired:1];
   [tapRecognizer setDelegate:self];
   [scrollview addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];


-(void)tapped:(id)sender {
      [textField resignFirstResponder];
      //    your code what you want
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using `xib` then just connect a `tapRecognizer` to your `scrollview` and then create `tapRecognizer's` selector event to `[self.view endEditing:YES]`

Answer (score 0):

```
add custom button on scrollview and
-(IBAction)btn:(id)sender
{
  [txt resignfirstresponder];
}

enjoy it!!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UITapGestureRecognizer *tapScroll = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc]initWithTarget:self     action:@selector(Click)];
ScrollClick.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
[YOUR scrollview addGestureRecognizer:ScrollClick];


- (void)Click
{
 [self.view endEditing:YES];
}
```

Try this one. And i hope it will be helpful For You . enjoy it !