# iOS: UIControl in UIScrollView not registering click events

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview, xcode5

I have a UIControl within a UIScrollView. I scrollview has a textfield. I want the text field to loose focus when the UIControl is touched.

This is the method the UIControl is hooked up to:

```
- (IBAction) clickedBackground
{
    [self.view endEditing:YES]; //make the view end editing!

}
```

But, the UIControl doesn't seem to call this event when touched. 
I did try this as suggested elsewhere, but to no avail:

```
[scroller setDelaysContentTouches:YES];
```

Comment: show the code which creates the control and binds the event.

Comment: The control was created using the interface builder. 
Control-dragged to bind.

Comment: Has your scroll view any custom gesture recognizer ?

Comment: @Tanguy. No, it doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The touch event on your UIControl is getting conflicted with touch event of your UIScrollView.

If you just to loose focus of the text field you can use on a button tap.

```
[textField resignFirstResponder];
```

But ideal way is to loose focus when user taps anywhere outside the text field. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143873/dismissing-the-keyboard-in-a-uiscrollview/11149702#11149702) would help you to achieve this.

However, if you just want to resign the keyboard. Then make use of **resignFirstResponder** on a button tap. You can also look into UITextField **input accessory view** in order to display a button on the keyboard input view that user can tap on.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using "scrollView.keyboardDismissMode = UIScrollViewKeyboardDismissModeOnDrag;" from the link you provided.