# iOS : recognize touch on UI scrollView

Tags: ios, swift

hi Im new to programming I was try to recognize the user touch on the screen and close all textfield but when I add a scrollview I won't be able to do that I read a lot in stack overflow like : tap recognizer but I could not do that anymore after adding the textfield I got confused

tell me how can I do it please?

thanks

Comment: what do you want to do ?

Comment: close all textfield after touching

Comment: You can use touches begin method

Comment: yeah, you can do what @BhupatBheda says

Comment: it worked before I add UI scrollview

Comment: you can do this in multiple ways

Comment: so like what ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for dismiss the keyboard is the subview of UIView, then use

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)

}
```

for dismiss the keyboard is the subview of UIScrollview, then use in here  scroll view observes the userInteraction so "By setting userInteractionEnabled to NO for your scroll view".

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.yourSCrollviewName.endEditing(true)

}
```

for resign the keyboard in various types, the some other type has already answered in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143873/dismissing-the-keyboard-in-a-uiscrollview)

**update**

for hide the keyboard the create the `TapGesture for your scrollview`

```
    self.ScrollView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
   // ScrollView.keyboardDismissMode = .onDrag
    let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(doubleTapped))
    tap.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    self.ScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
```

and call the action as

```
  func doubleTapped() {
    // do something cool here
     self.ScrollView.endEditing(true)
}
```

Comment: I changed the name to my scrollview name it didn't work

Comment: @Mahdi - it surely works, can you show ur tried code

Comment: override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.ScrollView.endEditing(true)
    }

Comment: @Mahdi - are you assign the name of your scrollview, see this also for referece http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5143873/dismissing-the-keyboard-in-a-uiscrollview

Comment: are you tapped in above scrollview or outer in scrollview

Comment: yes I assign it and also check referencing outlet I know you answer is right but it dosent work for me

Comment: @Mahdi - then why accpet my answer, can you update the question

Comment: because logically you're answer is right but I don't know why for me isn't working

Comment: do we have any touch event for scrollview?

Comment: how do I attach

Comment: compress t=your project and attach in dropbox or sendspace and give the link

Comment: I will give you GitHub link just wait 1m

Comment: @Mahdi - sorry my bro, my answer is wrong for your concept , wait I update the answer

Comment: @Mahdi - you can download your project [here](https://www.sendspace.com/file/k6bq31)

Comment: @Mahdi - its ok my bro, run once and reply here , i will wait

Comment: @Mahdi - bz your scrollview frame occupy the window , so it will oberserve all interaction in here we need to add another interaction in superview

Comment: thanks a lot   and just one more it would be same for double tap

Comment: @Mahdi - yes , you can modiffy your tap tap.numberOfTapsRequired =`1`

Answer (score 0):

- You have to add tap gesture on ScrollView
- Add below code in action of gesture:

  self.yourSCrollviewName.endEditing(true)

Comment: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException and go to delegate file

Comment: let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(hideKeyboardOnTapped))
        tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
        self.ScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)

Answer (score 0):

```
let tapGesture = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(keyBoardHideOnTap))
tapGesture.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
self.ScrollView.addGestureRecognizer(tapGesture)


func keyBoardHideOnTap() {
    // do something cool here
     self.ScrollView.endEditing(true)
}
```